# display table in IE

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer

I have code like that:

```
var xPola = 10, //how many cols
    yPola = 10, //how many cols
    bokPola = 30, //size of cell
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];


var tablica = document.createElement('table');
body.appendChild(tablica);

for( var y = 0; y < yPola; y++ ) {
    var rzad = document.createElement('tr');
    tablica.appendChild(rzad);
    for( var x = 0; x < xPola; x++ ) {
        var pole = document.createElement('td');
        pole.setAttribute('width', bokPola);
        pole.setAttribute('height', bokPola);
        rzad.appendChild(pole);
    }
};
```

it works fine in FF, Chrome & Opera (it displays 10x10 table with 30px width&height rows). In IE nothing happens. I check in firebug lite and it is in HTML section, inside BODY tag but i see nothing. Whats wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should try `appendChild` after the child nodes have been built?

Comment: @budzor - You should accept answers for your questions if you want to receive help, do this by clicking the empty checkmark by the answer that best helped you solve the problem.

Comment: i did it immediately after i read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs a few tweaks:

```
var xPola = 10, //how many cols
    yPola = 10, //how many cols
    bokPola = 30, //size of cell
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];


var tablica = document.createElement('table');
body.appendChild(tablica);
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
tablica.appendChild(tbody);

for( var y = 0; y < yPola; y++ ) {
    var rzad = document.createElement('tr');
    tbody.appendChild(rzad);
    for( var x = 0; x < xPola; x++ ) {
        var pole = document.createElement('td');
        pole.innerHTML='&nbsp;';
        pole.style.width = pole.style.height = bokPola;
        rzad.appendChild(pole);
    }
}
```

IE needs a `<tbody>` in most cases, and wont' display empty cells, so it needs a space in there.

Comment: THANKS! i was looking everywhere 4 anwser

Comment: i also have to add for each cell some onclick action, i make it in FF like this:
    pole.setAttribute('onclick', 'javascript:FunctionName();'); 

how to do it in IE?

Comment: @budxor for both just do `pole.onclick = FunctionName;`

Comment: @budzor - Works here across the board, can you update or ask another question with the code you're trying included?